# Looking for OAUTH open source jar for java

Tags: rest, oauth, java

I have published a java REST API using war on tomcat 7, and I am looking for an easy to deploy open source OAUTH code that i can add to my code (preferably by using maven POM) and use it for securing the API.

What are my options?

Comment: Option #0: Build your own OAuth code for the API. It's super simple, and using an external library for signing a request sounds like major overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Google's OAuth Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/Setup)? The documentation says that you can use Maven to add it to your code.